# Validate on save in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, validation

Is it possible to make Eclipse validate code when a file is saved?

If so, is this possible with vanilla Eclipse (Luna in this case), or is additional fiddling required?

This question is about JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably mention what kind of code you mean.

As for **Java**, just ensure that `Project > Build Automatically` is checked, and "save" will not only trigger validation but full compilation (incrementally for the saved file and its dependents, that is).

If this doesn't work for you, check if the project has really been created as a Java project.